# How can I get the Windows product key to upgrade to Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10-upgrade

I am using a Toshiba Satellite laptop and I upgraded my Windows 7 Ultimate operating system to Windows 10. But Windows did not activate. I contacted Microsoft support and they tried but they were not able to get the product key. How can I get it?

Comment: Contact with Microsoft how ? So if the company who makes it and you got in touch with them and they couldn't help what makes you think su can help

Answer (score 2):

I think your windows 7 wasn't activated (may be cracked), so windows 10 isn't activated as well. For further information go to [windows 10 upgrade support](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/help-upgrade-windows-10). If you didn't find a right solution contact [Microsoft support](https://partner.support.services.microsoft.com/en-us/contact/menu/software/windows/setup/).

Answer (score 1):

Check the bottom of the laptop. Usually there is a sticker that shows the key on it. Let me know if you find it

If you don't, then message the manufacturer of the laptop, they will usually give you one.